# Some trouble with derived classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, object

I am trying to implement the functions and classes below, but the output for arr[i].x is wrong. I correctly get arr[0].x = 0 and arr[1].x = 0, but arr[2].x does not return 0. Any ideas why?

```
class Base {
public:
  int x;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
int y;
void init(Base *b);
void foo();
};

void Derived :: init(Base *b) {
  for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    b[i].x = 0;
  }
}

void Derived :: foo() { 
  Derived arr[3];
  init(arr);
  for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  cout<<"b["<<i<<"] "<<arr[i].x;
  }
}


int main()
{
    Derived der;
    der.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void Derived :: foo() { 
    Derived arr[3];
    init(arr);
```

a pointer to `Derived`, `Derived*`, is passed to function `init(Base *b)`. What happens next is that instead of moving by the `sizeof(Derived)=8` in the table your function will move by `sizeof(Base)=4` what results in initialization of `x` member for first and second `Derived` in array and for `y` of first `Derived`, but not for `x` of last `Derived`.

> Pointer arithmetic is done based on the size of the type of the
>   pointer

Consider this memory layout (on x64):

### in Derived::foo():

```
Derived arr[3];

0x7fffffffe310  // 1st Derived, also address of arr[0].x
+8 = 
0x7fffffffe318  // 2nd Derived, also address of arr[1].x
+8 = 
0x7fffffffe320  // 3rd Derived, also address of arr[2].x
```

### but in Derived::init( Base* b):

```
b[0].x = 0x7fffffffe310  // set arr[0].x to 0
+4 =
b[1].x = 0x7fffffffe314  // set arr[0].y to 0
+4 =
b[2].x = 0x7fffffffe318  // set arr[1].x to 0
```

Thus, you have set arr[0].x to 0, arr[1].x to 0 and incidentally arr[0].y to 0. This is not what you want. Solution is to change Derived::init to

```
void Derived::init( Derived *d) {
  for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    d[i].x = 0;
  }
}
```

or even better, following principle of more generic programming:

```
template < size_t N>
void Derived::init( Derived (&d)[N] ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        d[i].x = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that init() has no idea that you are really passing a Derived* instead of a Base*.

So the loop in the init() function, the assumption is made that to get to the next entry in the array, sizeof(Base) is added to the pointer, not sizeof(Derived).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
cout<<"b["<<i<<"] "<<arr[i].x;
```

to

```
cout<<"b["<<i<<"] "<<arr[i].x<<endl;
```

Then you will see the correct number.

The extra function of endl is to flush the buffer associated with this stream. if you don't do that, it will output some random number sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

For one you're passing the pointer (*b) to the function init() by value, not by reference.

[Here's a nice explanation as to why that matters](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/) They explain it better than I likely could

Try making the function init look like this

```
init(Base& *b)
```

See what happens.

Comment: The function doesn't want to change the pointer.